# How to insert the object in LIST_ENTRY routine in windows?

Tags: winapi, device-driver, wdk

Can you please tell me the how to insert the object in LIST_ENTRY routine? I need to keep the many object in list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide much to work with.  Here are some of the routines associated with LIST_ENTRY management:

[InitializeListHead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[InsertHeadList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547820%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[AppendTailList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj673018%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[RemoveEntryList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561029%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[PushEntryList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559964%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[PopEntryList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559712%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[RemoveHeadList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[RemoveTailList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561036%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There are also interlocked versions of insert, remove, push, and pop.
And the general overview for singly and doubly linked lists for LIST_ENTRY
(Doubly Linked Lists use LIST_ENTRY - Scroll down to that section):

[Singly and Doubly Linked Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I hope this helps.